# div tag on top of flash

Tags: css, flash

http://www.starcraft-source.com/tv/#stream-35

The orange box and navigation is showing up behind the flash on the main site... how can I fix this?

I experience the issue in Google chrome

-- I've added that parameter, it doesn't seem to have any effect on this one: http://www.starcraft-source.com/tv/#stream-27

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add wmode to both `object`(IE) and `embed`(Firefox, Webkit, etc) tags:

```
<object width="..." height="..." ...>
   ...
   <param name="wmode" value="transparent">
   <embed width="..." height="..." wmode="transparent" ...></embed>
</object>
```

Answer (score 5):

Add this parameter to your Flash.

```
<param NAME="wmode" VALUE="transparent">
```