# IE Z-Index Help

Tags: internet-explorer, z-index

Nav bar needs to be on higher z-index so it appears above page elements like Flash and videos - currently it is behind them (http://bit.ly/dW0LYN), but seems if I put the ul li ul on -100 or 100 z-index it does nothing. What am I missing here? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354434/div-tag-on-top-of-flash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding `<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />` to your flash objects.
Can you also specify what version of IE are you using?

Comment: is there a dynamic way of doing that via css? if so what would the id be?

Comment: @HollerTrain: No, but you can use SWFObject and do it with JavaScript `myMovie.addParam("wmode", "transparent");`

Comment: See: http://cssbeauty.com/skillshare/discussion/1419/display-div-on-top-of-flash-object/

Comment: if the flash element will always be in the content div, then couldn't i just make the content div `z-index:0` and that would work on any flash element that is in the content?

Comment: Flash movies embedded into HTML files are not affected by the z-index. This results in the Flash movies to sit on top of any other content on the page..

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild objects with needed options:

```
$('object embed').each(function (index, element) {
    // 
    var $element = $(element);
    var $object = $element.closest('object');
    $element.attr('wmode', 'transparent');
    $object.append('<param name="wmode" value="opaque" />');
    // 
    var $updated = $($object[0].outerHTML);
    $updated.find('div').remove();
    // 
    $object.after($updated).remove();
});
```